# How Can I make a variable global to be accessed on every page in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two block of codes on one page in different parts of the page any time I try to use `$product_id` variable on the other segment of the code it is not recongnised. Take a look.

```
<?php
$cart_table = mysql_query("select  * from order_details where memberID='$ses_id' and status='Delivered' and addon_status=''") or die(mysql_error());
$cart_count = mysql_num_rows($cart_table);
while ($cart_row = mysql_fetch_array($cart_table)) {
    $order_id = $cart_row['orderid'];
    $status = $cart_row['status'];
    $product_id = $cart_row['productID'];
    $orderdate = $cart_row['ordertime'];
    //Query Product table
    $product_query = mysql_query("select * from tb_products where productID='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $product_row = mysql_fetch_array($product_query);

    //Query treat_period table
}
?>
```

I want to use `$product_id` variable on the next php block of code but but it is not recongnised at all. Somebody please help me.

```
<?php
require_once'session.php';

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_addon WHERE memberid='$ses_id' && productID='$product_id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sta=$row['treat_kind'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You're storing this `$product_id ` within the loop. That means the id changes every time. So, in your next query, do you want to match all product id's? Or a specific product id?

Comment: I want to match a specific product id

Comment: Then you need to create product ids array

Comment: Is this in the same file? If so can cart table have multiple rows. What error do u get when u use it, because even if u get multiple rows u should get the last product-id used in while loop. And ofc you should stop using mysql and go for pdo or mysqli because mysql is deprecated

Comment: I am trying to reference or use the product id from the first query in the second one. Just referencing the product id variable in the second query

Comment: The error  i now normally get is no result is returned

Comment: Your question or your expected result absolutely makes no sense. How are you supposed to get the specific product id? Based on what? Also, can be it a single product id or multiple product ids? You need to clear these basic things before you dump your question expecting someone to solve it for you..

Comment: Why do you have 2 queries? Why don't you use a join in your query to get the data from both tables in one go?

Answer (score 0):

PHP lets you use variables throughout the whole file. The reason product_id is not defined is probably because either your query doesn't return any results or product_id is null or blank.

Try this: var_dump($cart_row) right before your query and see if product ID exists and is not empty

Comment: the query is returning a result in the first block of code but is not recognised in the second block of codes